# Is x++ more efficient than x = x + 1 and x += 1 in assembly?

Tags: assembly, pic

I know a bit about assembly programming in Microchip PIC micro controllers, but I am not an expert.

Can somebody explain me out of the following 3 statements which is most efficient (i.e. less time consuming) in assembly.

```
x++
x = x + 1
x += 1
```

I am quite familiar with both C# and Java and I know for sure that there is no difference in efficiency in above 3 statements when we consider a high level programming language. But is there a difference in efficiency when we consider assembly?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you translate them to assembly?

Comment: Why not try to disassemble your code and check out yourself? Use `-S` option with gcc

Comment: If you know only a bit about PIC assembly you already know enough: it's the one that uses the least lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't assembly statements, you're working at the wrong level of abstraction.

Figuring out which of those C-like statements is faster would require compiling them into assembly then examining *that.*

Any non-braindead compiler will give you exactly the same code for all three cases.

If you *have* a braindead compiler then, yes, there'll almost certainly be a difference between things like:

```
inc  [memloc]
```

and:

```
lod  r1, [memloc]
inc  r1
sto [memloc], r1
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo.. I see your point.. The efficiency really depends on the compiler as well as the instruction set of the micro controller or processor..

Answer (score 2):

> there is no difference in efficiency in above 3 statements when we consider a high level programming language

This depends on your definition of "high level".  In scripting languages such as Python or Ruby, I would expect that `x++` outperforms `x += 1` and `x = x + 1`, since there is minimum symbol table lookup for `x`, and no scalar has to be "unboxed" (convert the scripting language `1` to assembly `1`).

For compiled languages such as C, however, I would expect that all three statements result in similar assembly code, so they should be equally efficient.  However, this depends on your compiler and its configuration, e.g., if you are performing a "debug" or "release" build.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers now are smart enough to find the best solution, so actually there all are the same.Compiler will convert them to fastest assembly command. So don't think about that. It's the last thing you should think about if you're writing C# or Java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, if these will be equally efficient when used in high level language: They will be, assuming you use any fairly decent compiler.

If you are asking, if using three different assembly instruction similar to above statements will be equally fast, then possibly not. If your CPU has special "inc" instruction, then probably it's a bit faster than others, if for nothing else (modern CPUs typically only need one cycle for such simple instructions) because instruction is probably shorter, which requires CPU to transfer less code from memory in long run. To be certain, you should check  the instruction set manual, where timings are often specified. For some architectures you can also get cycle accurate simulators, that should be able to answer those kinds of questions.